# PHP Strip String, Convert to int

Tags: php, string, int

I have a STRING `$special` which is formatted like `£130.00` and is also an ex TAX(VAT) price.

I need to strip the first char so i can run some simple addition.

```
$str= substr($special, 1, 0);  // Strip first char '£'
echo $str ;                    // Echo Value to check its worked
$endPrice = (0.20*$str)+$str ; // Work out VAT
```

I don't receive any value when i echo on the second line ? Also would i then need to convert the string to an integer in order to run the addition ?

Thanks

Matt

+++ UPDATE

Thanks for your help with this, I took your code and added some of my own, There are more than likely nicer ways to do this but it works :) I found out that if the price was below 1000 would look like £130.00 if the price was a larger value it would include a break. ie £1,400.22.

```
$str = str_replace('£', '', $price);
$str2 = str_replace(',', '', $str);
$vatprice = (0.2 * $str2) + $str2;
$display_vat_price = sprintf('%0.2f', $vatprice);
echo "£";
echo $display_vat_price ;
echo " (Inc VAT)";
```

Thanks again, Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `substr` the way you are using it currently. This is because you are trying to remove the `£` char, which is a two-byte unicode character, but `substr()` isn't unicode safe. You can either use `$str = substr($string, 2)`, or, better, `str_replace()` like this:

```
$string = '£130.00';
$str = str_replace('£', '', $string);
echo (0.2 * $str) + $str; // 156
```

---

**Original answer**

I'll keep this version as it still can give some insight. The answer would be OK if `£` wouldn't be a 2byte unicode character. Knowing this, you can still use it but you need to start the sub-string at offset `2` instead of `1`.

---

Your usage of `substr` is wrong. It should be:

```
$str = substr($special, 1);
```

Check the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) the third param would be the length of the sub-string. You passed `0`, therefore you got an empty string. If you omit the third param it will return the sub-string starting from the index given in the first param until the end of the original string.

Comment: Hello This now echos the first value as 130.000, But the second addition does not display anything ? I will keep trying. Thanks for your help